# How to show warning alert when app enters in to the background?

Tags: ios, swift

this question is duplicate but still i need help on this question because i use one of VPN app that app shows an alert if i close the app while connecting to the server, i'm also need to do same type of work while i'm connected to server in app. i need to restrict the user to keep the app open if user press home button then need to notify user to keep open the app for his online status.

Answer (score 0):

> for iPhone, you can't forbid user press home button.

> Maybe if you app enter background, you can push a local notification, notify user, keep your app online.  I think this is a good idea.